# centering google captcha and send button on "contact form 7"

Tags: wordpress, captcha, send

I am trying to center the google captcha and the send button of contact form 7 on this web page:
http://p17238-110-2914.s110.upress.link/contact/

I tried `margin: 0 auto;` and wrapping it with a `div` without any success: [my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqfE4.png)

Answer (score 1):

Around the capcha iframe, you have a div within inline style:

```
style="width: 304px; height: 78px;"
```

Remove this and add `display:block` and `margin: auto` to the iframe

Hope this helps.